# Dual boot going straight to fedora without giving options

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, grub

I have a laptop with windows 10 in it. I have installed fedora 29 in parallel to this windows 10. I wanted to create a dual boot system but now whenever I switch on my laptop, it directly boots via fedora. I have tried many solutions related to grub but nothing seems to work.
I have already tried `sudo update-grub` but this gives me `sudo: update-grub: command not found`

How I can make my laptop dual boot?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your Win10 installation is detectable and did not get destroyed during the Fedora installation this should do the trick:

`sudo update-grub`

This will make grub run through it's config scripts, which SHOULD detect all bootable partitions and generate appropriate entries for them.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. However, I have tried this before and whenever I try to run this I get "sudo: update-grub: command not found"

Comment: 1) You can try `update-grub2` 2) you can try `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (for which update-grub is an alias), 3) If all else fails try to reinstall grub using your package manager.

Comment: I have just tried 1 and 2. 1 is giving "command not found" for update-grub2 and 2 is giving "command not found" for grub-mkconfig. Can you please tell me how to reinstall grub using package manger?

Comment: This should help you get started: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2