# Modify grub to dual boot fedora with windows 10

Tags: linux, fedora, windows, dual-boot

I am trying to dual boot fedora with windows 10. I am new to linux. 
I have found this code to be written in 40_custom file in grub.

```
menuentry "Windows 10" { 
set root='(hd0,1)'
 chainloader +1 
}
```

But this does not seem to work. It says cannot find disk. I have my windows in `/dev/sda3` What should I write in 40_custom file so that i can use dual boot properly?

EDIT:  My laptop had windows 10 pre installed when I had bought it. I have installed fedora 29 workstation. I do see the grub screen but the windows 10 option there(Created due to the above code) tells disk not found. Windows boot entry was not created automatically when I had installed fedora

Comment: Was your PC sold to you with a Windows 10 logo sticker on it?  Basically any pre-installed Windows 10 should be using EFI boot.  And EFI boot does not work with the `chainloader +1` approach.

Comment: I am not certain, but it is possible that you booted the Fedora installer in BIOS mode instead of EFI mode.  Is your Fedora system booting in EFI mode?  You can tell because `ls -l /sys/firmware/efi` will work in EFI mode, otherwise it will show "not found".

Comment: I have edited the statements accordingly. I think I have installed in BIOS mode as the above command gave "No such file or directory found" message

Comment: @sourcejedi then what approach should I take?

Comment: Is it convenient to re-install at this point?  Although, first please check that you have x86_64.  Fedora says it does not support UEFI on 32-bit.  Does `uname -p` show x86_64?

Comment: It is tricky to say how to make sure to boot the Fedora install in EFI mode, because the way you choose what to boot depends on your firmware / motherboard.  But, e.g. if you boot from USB and there is an option that says just "USB" and an option that says "USB - fedora", the EFI mode will be the one that says "fedora".  Even if the option does not explicitly say "EFI".

Comment: @sourcejedi yes it does show x86_64. Yes, I can reinstall but I am not sure whether my windows 10 is in UEFI or not becuse I had reinstalled it some months back. Is there any way to be sure about this prior to re-installation?

Comment: I.e. is it convenient to re-install Fedora?  You can carefully delete the old Fedora partitions and start again.  No need to re-install Windows, just be careful not to delete the Windows partition or EFI System Partition (ESP) that Windows uses by mistake.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows+am+i+using+efi

Comment: @sourcejedi can I delete fedora partitions when I am using fedora? Coz I am unable to open windows..

Comment: The Fedora Installer can delete partitions.  It might not be the best way, i.e. the safest one that makes it easiest to be sure what you are deleting.  I am not sure.  links: [gparted live medias](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd).  [official Fedora Install guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f29/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda/#sect-installation-gui-storage-partitioning), search for "reclaim space"

Comment: P.S. this question should really have been an edit to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512231/dual-boot-going-straight-to-fedora-without-giving-options?rq=1 .  I.e. this is a second solution you tried to solve your problem in the first question.  Of course it is good that you showed all the solutions you tried (and failed) before you asked the question here.

Comment: BTW, in case you urgently need to boot Windows, you should be able to go into your firmware boot menu or settings - the same place you used to boot the Fedora installer - and it should have an option to boot Windows.  So in theory you could use Windows to delete the Fedora partitions, although that would not be my preferred method.

Comment: I will try to locate it.. Because I have not found any way to boot from windows.

Comment: If there is an option to disable "BIOS CSM" (compatibility support), then it would have to boot an EFI operating system :-).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give it another try to boot Windows...

This only works if your EFI partition is still intact.

1. Run `lsblk -no UUID /dev/sda3` and write down the UUID.
2. Edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and change `67E3-17ED` to your UUID:

   ```
   menuentry "Windows 10" {
       insmod part_gpt
       insmod fat
       set root='hd0,gpt1'
       search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 67E3-17ED
       chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
   }
   ```
3. Update `grub.cfg`

   Please check which file exists, i.e. `ls /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` or `ls /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`. It's probably the first one.

   If you booted from legacy BIOS, this should be

   ```
   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
   ```

   and from UEFI

   ```
   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
   ```
4. Reboot and test

Comment: When I executed step 1, many lines came up.. I cannot understand which is the UUID. Any help?

Comment: @ArnabBanerjee You can see the UUID also with `ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid`. Then select the one of `../../sda3`.

Comment: My windows is in dev/sda3... So in the menuentry will it be gpt1 or gpt3?

Comment: @ArnabBanerjee I think `set root='hd0,gpt1'` refers to the EFI partition, so leave this as it is. Only change the UUID.

Comment: Do I need to give single or double quotes around the uuid?

Comment: @ArnabBanerjee No quotes. Just replace the value 67E3-17ED.

Comment: I have tried this just now but its still not working. It says bootmgfw.efi file not found

Comment: @ArnabBanerjee Then it seems your Windows is also not bootet by UEFI. What is `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`?

Comment: I have manually found the file bootmgfw.efi and I have replaced the path after chainloader now. Now it says chainloader.c:213:invalid signature. Also I think my windows is in UEFI as my partitions are in gpt

Comment: @ArnabBanerjee Ok, where did you found it or what's the new path? I have no idea what the error means...

Comment: Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi

Comment: @ArnabBanerjee I also have it at that location and just bootet from (hd0,2)/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi (sda2 is my Win10) instead of the one in /EFI dir,  so the problem must be somewhere else.